# Header top image show problem in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, extensions, css

I am using joomla 2.5 with jsn_yoyo_pro template. and the JSN Image_Show for a slider. This slider is working properly in some resolution, for a higher resolution its overlapping the header menu.
How to fix this problem?

[image]

If I make that style height:100% then its working properly. But I didnt get the source code. Please help me.

My site url is : [mysite url](http://www.neurotrauma2015.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom css file which will override your template/slider css.

From what I remember if you're using the jsn framework > go to;

template settings > SEO and system settings > Custom CSS file > add your custom css code here. (this location could have changed since I last used this FW though!)

Your custom css should be something like;

```
.jsn-homepage #jsn-header-top {
height: 100% !important;
}
```

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: its not allowing this code in that field . defaultly their is "custom.css"

Comment: Do you have a file named custom.css in the location @Neil has described below? If not, create one and add the css code provided. Clear cache, refresh browser.

Comment: thank you so much . i saved this code as custom1.css and put that name in template settings > SEO and system settings > Custom CSS file > instd of writing code. it works . thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to override the height by adding to your custom CSS file at `/templates/jsn_yoyo_pro/css/custom.css` like this or similar:

```
#jsn-header-top {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: no.nothing is their in custom.css  .

Comment: I can see some existing custom code at: http://www.neurotrauma2015.org//templates/jsn_yoyo_pro/css/custom.css but am not familiar with how best to edit this as I'm not a Joomla Shine user. I assume it can be edited directly?

Comment: we can edit here.tell me where i need to edit . i will edit

Comment: You just need to insert the suggested code.